# Read from different mysql databases and write to common mysql database in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I want to implement a spring batch job which does the following:

- Start job
- Start multiple parallel flows:

  - Flow 1: Read from database 1 and process.
  - Flow 2: Read from database 2 and process.
- Insert the data into database 3

I know that I can insert the database inside individual flows itself, but I think that will introduce the problem of concurrent access on the same table rows from multiple places as different threads would be writing to the same table in db3.

I initially thought I can use a Tasklet for inserting into db3 but I don't understand how to get the data from flow1 and flow2 into the final tasklet.

Any clues on how to achieve this?

Edit for more clarification:

- The job is used to migrate legacy data into a new db that has a different structure. The data needed for the new table is scattered across legacy databases
- Flow 1 and Flow 2 are not dependent on each other. Both of these flows get their respective data from different legacy databases and maps it to the new structure.
- Now given that the structure (after processing) from both of these flows would be the same, I want to collect them and then insert them into the new database.

Comment: Are flow1 and flow2 interdependent in some way? Are you trying to join or group data from these two flows before writing it to database 3? Please give an example with some real input/output records to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added more explanation for the question. Please have a look.

Comment: ok thanks for the update. This is not related to Spring Batch per se, it is rather a data processing requirement for which you need to figure out a solution that could be implemented with Spring Batch. The title of your question should really be "Read from different mysql databases and write to common mysql database" first. Do you have already a solution to this problem (and you are looking to implement it with Spring Batch) or are you looking for help to find a solution?

Comment: So, due to some restraints, I need to go with the spring-batch approach. I could think of the above-mentioned approach but can't figure out how to implement it. Also, open to some other approach but with spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

> Flow 1 and Flow 2 are not dependent on each other [..] the structure (after processing) from both of these flows would be the same

Since flows are not dependent on each others and they produce the same structure to be written to DB3, you can create two chunk-oriented steps that run in parallel, each one reading from a different database.

> I want to group them and then insert them into the new database.

Since you need to group items, a common technique is to write them to one or more staging tables on which you can do the grouping/aggregation before the final write to destination. Without this need for grouping, you could have written data from both flows directly to DB3.